# Why "sfdx force:auth:web:login" encounters runtime error, and how to get around it?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am trying to develop with Salesforce DX. There is a new problem since I restarted this project after a two-month break. Every variation of the auth:web:login command fails the same way. force:org:list also elicits the same error. My environment is Ubuntu 16.04 (Linux). What to do? Terminal session:

> me@here:~/Projects/sfdx-simple$ sfdx force:auth:web:login
>
> TypeError: ts_types_1.getString is not a function
>       at AuthWebLoginCommand.catch (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/salesforce-alm/dist/ToolbeltCommand.js:172:24)
>        at AuthWebLoginCommand._run (/usr/local/lib/sfdx/node_modules/@salesforce/command/lib/sfdxCommand.js:95:29)
>
> me@here:~/Projects/sfdx-simple$ sfdx -v sfdx-cli/7.8.1-8f830784cc
>   linux-x64 node-v10.15.3
>
> me@here:~/Projects/sfdx-simple$ node -v v10.15.3
>
> me@here:~/Projects/sfdx-simple$ sfdx plugins --core
>   @oclif/plugin-commands 1.2.2 (core) @oclif/plugin-help 2.1.6 (core)
>   @oclif/plugin-not-found 1.2.2 (core) @oclif/plugin-plugins 1.7.8
>   (core) @oclif/plugin-update 1.3.9 (core)
>   @oclif/plugin-warn-if-update-available 1.7.0 (core)
>   @oclif/plugin-which 1.0.3 (core) @salesforce/sfdx-trust 3.0.2 (core)
>   analytics 1.1.2 (core) generator 1.1.0 (core) salesforcedx 45.16.0
>   (core) ├─ force-language-services 45.12.0 (core) └─ salesforce-alm
>   45.18.0 (core)
>
> sfdx-cli 7.8.1 (core)
>
> me@here:~/Projects/sfdx-simple$ sfdx plugins no plugins installed
>
> me@here:~/Projects/sfdx-simple$

Comment: Have you tried `sfdx update` followed by `sfdx plugins:update`? This can often resolve most runtime issues.

Comment: Tried it but it had no effect, which makes sense, since it is a recent re-install of Node, Salesforce CLI, and sfdx .

Comment: BTW this works fine on my Windows 10 system. I will test on other Ubuntu 16.04 machines.

Comment: Commands work normally on another machine with a fresh install of sfdx on Ubuntu 16.04. That install brought Node 15.10.3 with it. The problem machine also has Node 16.0 and I suspect there is a snafu amongst the installations and re-installations of Node, and/or nvm, npm, vsCode, sfdx, and the vsCode extensions.  Time to burn it all with a blowtorch and re-install!

Comment: It works, after a thorough cleaning and re-install!

Comment: It'd be great if you wrote up a quick answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

Got something similar:

> ts_types_1.has is not a function

**Resolution**

I had to uninstall the Salesforce CLI and reinstall to resolve the error.

Comment: This worked for me.  May be some issue between the CLI extension in VS Code and the CLI program.  Whatever it is, uninstall/reinstall fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted nvm, npm, vsCode, Node, and sfdx. I uninstalled what I could, and deleted all files that remained. Then I reinstalled vsCode, sfdx, the vsCode extensions, and Node 15.10.3 . Once I did that, it all worked again. So I don't know what was wrong, but I suspect that there is an incompatibility with Node 16.0 . I usually follow these rules: Never install a ".0" release (Node 16.0), and, Never install software that isn't required (nvm, npm).